# ffmpeg keyframerate can't setup

Tags: ffmpeg, settings

I need setting keyframe for youtube but not working. Is on linux Debian.

```
ffmpeg -i "test.flv" -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=120:no-scenecut -sameq -pix_fmt yuv420p -re -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -bufsize 2048k -vb 400k -maxrate 800k -deinterlace -acodec libmp3lame -preset medium -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/"
```

I have error Unrecognized option 'x264-params'

Comment: Try with `-x264opts`.  Your ffmpeg may be too old; upgrade. And remove `-sameq`. Not useful.

Comment: Thank you but same. Unrecognized option 'x264opts'  
root@martin5504:~# ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 0.8.20-6:0.8.20-0+deb7u1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 19 2017 12:10:13 with gcc 4.7.2

Comment: Your ffmpeg is extremely old and it's not even real ffmpeg. Get current one from www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: But now I have this problem. Option re (read input at native frame rate) cannot be applied to output url rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/6gte-0euh-v0zj-4a13 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for output file rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

Comment: Place `-re` before `-i test.flv`

Comment: Not is good, but now video is skipping frames after few seconds.